# google authentication return access denied after authorization page via owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin, google-authentication

I try to authenticate my user using Microsoft and Google authentication services. Microsoft Service works without problem but I have problem with google one.

To summarize my explanation , I did following tasks in google console manager:

1. enable google+ API (and even google+ domains API).
2. add two redirect URL to my project : http://{my website}/signin-google , http://{my website}/account/externallogincallback

and I configure my web application  like follows:

```
 var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {//www.mylocal.com Site clientId
        ClientId = "my client Id",
        ClientSecret = "my secret",
    };
app.UseGoogleAuthentication( googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

Problem is : 
When a user try to login using google , it redirect to google authorization page successfully, but when he authorize my application , he will redirect to my callback , but my application does not have access to his data.

you can see my website problem using following link.

[my website](http://danashr.com)

Comment: I have never tried to use GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions but if you don't add any scopes I don't think your going to have access to any data.

Comment: I should search for your response.@DalmTo

Comment: Or give me a few minutes to play with it or check out the Google .net client library up to you :)

Comment: Try adding this:   googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("profile");

Comment: I have tested 3 different scopes. but didn't work.

Comment: Does the authentication window pop up and request access for those scopes?  How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I tested my site locally. window does not pop up, it redirects to google and my website. you can see my problem using my website.

Comment: Solved for me: I used VS2017 (ASP.NET MVC, Individual User Accounts), VS2013 may have old templates, activate https, added  https://{my website}/signin-google and  JavaScript https://{my website} in google, added "google+ API", finally put ClientId and Secret in My Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistakenly filled "**client secret**" with the value of "**client key**". When google service redirect the request to my web application (on server side), My application tried to access the data using incorrect client secret. In other word, google didn't return access token to my web application. This [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#webserver) explains more about my scenario. Following paragraph explain my situation.

> The authorization sequence begins when your application redirects a
>   browser to a Google URL; the URL includes query parameters that
>   indicate the type of access being requested. Google handles the user
>   authentication, session selection, and user consent. The result is an
>   authorization code, which the application can exchange for an access
>   token and a refresh token.